# Container with max-width won't wrap inline-block children when resized

Tags: html, css, containers, clearfix

I have this code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col {
    max-width: 150px;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: grey;
  font-size: 0;
}

.col {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper clearfix">
  <section class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120" alt="">
  </section>
  <section class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120" alt="">
  </section>
</section>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j77cd856/4/)

The container won't wrap around its elements when media query gets activated. The same thing happens with floated children (which is normal, I guess).

Comment: Here's a simple illustration to better convey my problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wggtj.png

Comment: you could try using floats instead too.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j77cd856/8/)

one option is to add an "inner" wrapper; just a wrapper within your wrapper. you can make it `display inline-block` and set `text-align center` on the parent wrapper. Finally, remove the grey background from the wrapper and apply to the inner wrapper.

just one drawback is that when you make the window really small the .col divs are not lined up on the left. not sure if that's an issue for you

html

```
<section class="wrapper clearfix">
     <div class='inner-wrap'>
        <section class="col">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120" alt="">
        </section>
        <section class="col">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120" alt="">
        </section>
            </div>
    </section>
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col {
        max-width: 150px;
    }
}

.inner-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    background: grey;
}
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
}

.col {
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.col:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```